# Tapping Laptop Touchpad problem

Tags: mouse, touchpad, system-settings, libinput

I have an Ubuntu 16.04 OS and whenever I hover my mouse over the application such as Firefox, I tap the touchpad but it doesn't open up the application until I actually press on the touchpad until it clicks. Is there a way to enable my touchpad so that I just need to tap it to make it open up certain apps. Thank you.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `xinput` terminal command. Also find out the touchpad id from that output and post the output of `xinput list-props <id>` command. Probably `libinput` is installed.

Comment: What I was saying was that the touchpad on my laptop has to be pushed down on so I can actually click something rather than just simply tapping it and so I wanted to figure out how to fix that problem so that I can just tap on it rather than push down on it. Also I found that `libinput` is installed, so what should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run `sudo -H gedit /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/90-libinput.conf`

and add

```
Option "Tapping" "true"
```

to the end of the touchpad section of that file. Tapping is disabled in `libinput` in Ubuntu 16.04.

Save the file and reboot.

Comment: It didn't work unfortunately, this is what I got `(gedit:3416): Gtk-WARNING **: Calling Inhibit failed: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name org.gnome.SessionManager was not provided by any .service files

** (gedit:3416): WARNING **: Set document metadata failed: Setting attribute metadata::gedit-spell-language not supported

** (gedit:3416): WARNING **: Set document metadata failed: Setting attribute metadata::gedit-encoding not supported`

Comment: It does not matter what appears in the terminal. An editor window should be opened. Edit the file there.